# Node.js response issue during AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

Maybe this seems a really noob question, but I can't figure out what I do wrong. What I want to accomplish is a simple AJAX request. Here is my code on server side:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"     
        });
        response.end("No data to return.");

}).listen(8666);
```

On client side I use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#magicSend").on("click", function() {
            $.ajax({                   
               url: "http://localhost:8666/",
               type: "POST"
             });
        });
    });
```

The problem is, that according to Firebug I'm getting the response headers but not the content. The AJAX call also gets red on Firebug's console, although it shows "200 OK". I know I miss something but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running your webserver on port 8666 also? Judging by your code, all your NodeJS server does is serve a single answer, so I'm guessing not. **You cannot make AJAX calls to a different port, even if it's the same host (localhost in your case).**

Comment: I'm running a simple LAMPP server, which runs on port 80. I used as example the code from the first answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011984/basic-ajax-send-receive-with-node-js

Comment: I found a workaround by using JSONP, as described here: http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

Comment: Like I said, you cannot use AJAX calls on seperate hostnames/ports. JSONP is a valid work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Is not working because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

It maybe not obvious but browsers also enforce the policy down-to the port number.

So http://example.com:80 is different from http://example.com:81

You can get around it with [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).