# returning data from server to an ajax request sent in client side javascript

Tags: node.js, jquery, client-side

- Node.js web server
- Request handler in web server

> ```
> app.get('/documents/:id.:format?', function(req, res) {
>    **dataTobeSentToClientSideJavaScript** = processRequest (req);
>    ... 
> })
> ```

- ajax request from client side javascript

  > ```
  > var request = $.ajax({
  > url: "/documents/xxx",
  > });
  > request.done(handleResponse);
  > ```
- I am able to receive the request on server side

What code should be written on server side so that I can populate the "handleRespone" object expected in my ajax request above with dataTobeSentToClientSideJavaScript created on server side?

Comment: It helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011984/basic-ajax-send-receive-with-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use methods exposed by the response object such as res.write, res.end or res.json

take a look at http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse
(Node.js API)

and since you're using Express - http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.status