# nodejs cannot serve static files - downloads them

Tags: ajax, node.js

I am playing around with nodejs, creating a simple server, also handles some ajax. When I go to `localhost:4000` the page does not render, instead an empty file is automatically downloaded. It is named "download file", zero byte and no extension.

I think my client and my server are really simple. Sorry for the generic question but I fail to understand why this is happening.

Thanks in advance

Client - a simple form and a XHR that sends json-type data

```
<html>
    <head>        <title>Chatrooms</title>    </head>    
    <body>
<form id="fruitform" method="post" action="/">
<div class="table">
<div class="row">
<div class="cell label">Bananas:</div>
<div class="cell"><input name="bananas" value="2"/></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell label">Apples:</div>
<div class="cell"><input name="apples" value="5"/></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell label">Cherries:</div>
<div class="cell"><input name="cherries" value="20"/></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell label">Total:</div>
<div id="results" class="cell">0 items</div>
</div>
</div>
<button id="submit" type="button">Submit Form</button>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
<div id="de"></div>

 </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = handleButtonPress;

function handleButtonPress(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = "";
    //gather all input values in a json type string
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
        formData += inputElements[i].name + "=" + inputElements[i].value + "&";     
    }
    formData = formData.slice(0, -1);
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "/formHandler", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = hr.responseText;
        }
    }
    hr.send(formData);
}
</script>
```

Server

```
//dependencies
var http = require ('http');
var fs = require ('fs');
var path = require ('path');
var mime = require ('mime');
var qs = require('querystring');


//this is the http server
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response){
    var filePath = false;
    if (request.url == '/'){
        filePath='public/index.html';//default static file
    }

    if (request.url == '/formHandler'){//handle XHR
            if (request.method=="POST"){
                var rrr="rrr";
                response.writeHead(200,{"content-type":"text/plain"});
                response.write(rrr);
                response.end(rrr);
            }
    }

    else{
        filePath='public'+request.url;//set relative file path
    }
    var absPath = './'+filePath;
    serveStatic(request, response, cache, absPath);//serve the static file

});

server.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log("Chatrooms server on port 4000");
    }
);

//read static files 
function serveStatic(request, response,cache, absPath){
    fs.readFile(absPath, function(err, data){
            sendFile(request, response, absPath, data);

    })
}

//serve file data
function sendFile(request, response, filePath, fileContents){
    response.writeHead(
        200,{"content-type":mime.lookup(path.basename(filePath))}
    );
    response.end(fileContents);     
}
```

UPDATE
If I remove the following part from the server, it works fine. Still cannot understand what is going on

```
    if (request.url == '/formHandler'){
        console.log("inside ajax if");
            console.log("inside formPro");
            if (request.method=="POST"){
                console.log("inside second ajax if");
                var rrr="rrr";
                response.writeHead(200,{"content-type":"text/plain"});
                response.write(rrr);
                response.end(rrr);
                console.log("finished sending rrr");
            }
    }
```

Comment: `fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(response)`, and check your errors

Comment: Bad headers, check your pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `fs.readFile` is returning an error, which you are ignoring.

When serving static files you should not read the whole thing into memory like this. The whole point of Node.JS is to keep I/O freely flowing.

Use `fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(response)` instead, although you will need to add an error listener, or run within a domain.

---

UPDATE

Bugs abound - you don't return from any cases and just carry through to the next one.

i.e. You can end up calling both `request.end()` and `serveStatic`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you to use node express module http://expressjs.com/
which will allow you to write custom template renderer as well as static pages including css and js image files

simply install express using

```
npm -g install express
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Dickens answer here is the basic express app that handles your form and all static files in `./public/`

```
//dependencies
var http = require ('http');
var express = require('express'); // npm install --save express
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.post('/formHandler', function(req, res){
  res.status(200).send('rrr');
})
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log("Chatrooms server on port 4000");
});


// Test with:
// curl -vX POST http://localhost:4000/formHandler
// curl -vX GET http://localhost:4000/index.html
```