# How can I retrieve the data object using SQL package on Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a **mysql query** executed from NodeJS using [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) npm package.

Upon success, I want to read the value in Javascript.

Both are on the same domain.

On `console.log` the value I read is `3`.

How can I retrieve the data object values?

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionOptions);

connection.query(
  "SELECT * FROM pruebas.Usuarios2 where RFC = '123'", 
  (err, result, fields) => { 
     if (result.length) { 
       // here I need an instruction that can send me the result of 3
       // to my javascript console
     } else { 
       console.log('no login');
     }
   }
 );
```

Comment: Have you read https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries ? 
You can try to add `console.log(JSON.stringify({ results, fields }));` within `if (result.length) { }` block

Comment: How are you calling this? From where? Is this running on some sort of server? Think we need some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't send from Node to Javascript. You call Node from Javascript using an Ajax call and return a value.

The answer to this question is a good exemple of how to do it: 
[Basic Ajax send/receive with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011984/basic-ajax-send-receive-with-node-js)

Comment: I guess this depends on how OP has set things up.

Comment: The only way I can think this can work in another way is setting a socket connection. Can you give an example of what you're thinking ?

Comment: As part of a response from say Express?

Comment: It's still an ajax call from js to Node isn't it ?

Comment: Can just be on a page load. If you make a call to certain endpoint, let the page refresh, and let express do its work (including the query) and return it. Not AJAX required.

Comment: Yes but that's only a request to the server directly by the browser. The OP asked how he can send a value from Node to Javascript. :)